# XLS Template issue with for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

Busy getting stuck in XSL templates and I'm having a slight issue.

Using the following template code:

**productlisting.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>TFG Product File</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>ProductID</th>
      <th>ProductName</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="ProductFile/Products">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ProductFile/Products/Id"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ProductFile/Products/LocalizedProductList/DisplayName"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is the XML file for two products:

**productcatalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="productlisting.xsl"?>
<ProductFile>
    <SiteId>1011</SiteId>
    <Products>
        <TFGMerchandisingId>251100AAAC0</TFGMerchandisingId>
        <Id>251100AAAC0</Id>
        <TFGMerchandisingDescription>MELTON COAT TOBACCO</TFGMerchandisingDescription>
        <TFGMerchandisingDescriptionLong>MELTON COAT TOBACCO</TFGMerchandisingDescriptionLong>
        <Type>ColourSize</Type>
        <SubType></SubType>
        <VideoUrl></VideoUrl>
        <TFGMerchandisingStatus>1</TFGMerchandisingStatus>
        <TFGMerchandisingStatusDescription>Open</TFGMerchandisingStatusDescription>
        <TFGMerchandisingCreateDate>2017-04-23T16:57:42.983</TFGMerchandisingCreateDate>
        <TFGMerchandisingPisDate>2017-03-31T00:00:00</TFGMerchandisingPisDate>
        <TFGMerchandisingCommodity>1100</TFGMerchandisingCommodity>
        <TFGMerchandisingCommodityDescription>FB SMART JACKETS</TFGMerchandisingCommodityDescription>
        <TFGMerchandisingBuyersClass>110001</TFGMerchandisingBuyersClass>
        <TFGMerchandisingBuyersClassDescription>OVERCOATS</TFGMerchandisingBuyersClassDescription>
        <TFGMerchandisingMaterial>WOOL BLENDS</TFGMerchandisingMaterial>
        <TFGMerchandisingWeight>0.00</TFGMerchandisingWeight>
        <TFGMerchandisingCubeVolume>0</TFGMerchandisingCubeVolume>
        <TFGMerchandisingBrandName>FABIANI</TFGMerchandisingBrandName>
        <BrandCode>25</BrandCode>
        <CrossSellProductId1></CrossSellProductId1>
        <CrossSellProductId2></CrossSellProductId2>
        <CrossSellProductId3></CrossSellProductId3>
        <DisableCompareOption>false</DisableCompareOption>
        <DisableNextDayDelivery>false</DisableNextDayDelivery>
        <RequiresRica>false</RequiresRica>
        <RequiresId>false</RequiresId>
        <RequiresTVLicense>false</RequiresTVLicense>
        <RequiresDeposit>false</RequiresDeposit>
        <InstallmentAvailable>false</InstallmentAvailable>
        <StaffDiscountAllowed>true</StaffDiscountAllowed>
        <StaffDiscountOverride>false</StaffDiscountOverride>
        <MaxDiscountAllowed>40.00</MaxDiscountAllowed>
        <SizeChartIconUrl></SizeChartIconUrl>
        <PdfIconUrl></PdfIconUrl>
        <IsNavigable>true</IsNavigable>
        <TFGMerchandisingTypeCode></TFGMerchandisingTypeCode>
        <TFGMerchandisingTypeDescription>FABIANI</TFGMerchandisingTypeDescription>
        <Groups>
            <GroupSequence>1</GroupSequence>
            <GroupId>8c5f3f15-7a57-4186-bd29-3f7f6a3b106f</GroupId>
            <LocalizedGroupList>
                <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                <Group>Default</Group>
            </LocalizedGroupList>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>9dd85915-f977-4596-9d35-10d3e23aef1c</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Style Detail</Name>
                    <Value>Peak lapels Fully lined Single vent Flap pockets</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>47fa52e8-44d6-45f3-8249-906434f6e399</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Size &amp; Fit</Name>
                    <Value>Regular Fit To ensure every Fabiani garment is the perfect fit for you, please refer to our size guide and check our measurements.</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>823e6a08-a906-4b2e-9fc1-35c332d263d0</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Fabric</Name>
                    <Value>Wool blends</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>1abbda7a-3f92-4eee-b414-7516c4eb0fe3</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Care</Name>
                    <Value>Do Not Wash Do Not Bleach Cool Iron Dry-clean Only Do Not Tumble Dry</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>479d96a4-f8a7-4048-876a-da9134d03ed1</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Models size</Name>
                    <Value>Model wearing a large Model measures: chest 39"/ 99cm, waist 32, height 74'02"/ 188cm</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
        </Groups>
        <LocalizedProductList>
            <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
            <DisplayName>MELTON COAT</DisplayName>
            <Description>A modern wardrobe essential, our stylish overcoat is expertly crafted into a slim yet unrestrictive silhouette from luxuriously soft Melton, ensuring warmth and comfort on colder days. The single vent allows for freedom of movement while the lining allows it to easily layer over jackets and knitwear.</Description>
            <Widget1Url></Widget1Url>
            <Widget2Url></Widget2Url>
            <Widget3Url></Widget3Url>
            <Tabs>
                <Name>Product Information</Name>
                <Description></Description>
            </Tabs>
            <SizeChartUrl></SizeChartUrl>
            <SizeChartToolTip></SizeChartToolTip>
            <PdfUrl></PdfUrl>
            <PdfToolTip></PdfToolTip>
            <SeoTitle>MELTON COAT</SeoTitle>
        </LocalizedProductList>
        <Colours>
            <TFGMerchandisingStyleId>21303875</TFGMerchandisingStyleId>
            <DefaultStyleId>21303875</DefaultStyleId>
            <TFGMerchandisingColourId>21303875</TFGMerchandisingColourId>
            <TFGMerchandisingColourDescription>LIGHT GREY</TFGMerchandisingColourDescription>
            <TFGMerchandisingGeneric>GREY</TFGMerchandisingGeneric>
            <ImageMainPrimary>/25/Detail/21303875.jpg</ImageMainPrimary>
            <ImageMainAlts>
                <URL>/25/DetailAlternative/21303875_01.jpg</URL>
            </ImageMainAlts>
            <ImageMainAlts>
                <URL>/25/DetailAlternative/21303875_02.jpg</URL>
            </ImageMainAlts>
            <ImageThumbPrimary>/25/Thumbnail/21303875.jpg</ImageThumbPrimary>
            <ImageThumbAlts>
                <URL>/25/ThumbnailAlternative/21303875_01.jpg</URL>
            </ImageThumbAlts>
            <ImageThumbAlts>
                <URL>/25/ThumbnailAlternative/21303875_02.jpg</URL>
            </ImageThumbAlts>
            <ImageSearchPrimary>/25/Listing/21303875.jpg</ImageSearchPrimary>
            <Swatch>/25/ColourSwatch/21303875_SW.jpg</Swatch>
            <DisableEmailMe>false</DisableEmailMe>
            <DisableAddToGiftList>false</DisableAddToGiftList>
            <DisableAddToWishList>false</DisableAddToWishList>
            <DisableAddToCart>false</DisableAddToCart>
            <RemoveFromOnlineCatalogue>false</RemoveFromOnlineCatalogue>
            <LocalizedColourList>
                <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                <SeoTitle></SeoTitle>
            </LocalizedColourList>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303883</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>8</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>44 CHEST L</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>44 CHEST L</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303885</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>10</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>46 CHEST L</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>46 CHEST L</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303884</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>9</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>46 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>46 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303876</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>3</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>36 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>36 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303889</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>14</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>54 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>54 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303888</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>13</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>52 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>52 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303882</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>7</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>44 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>44 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303878</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>5</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>40 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>40 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303886</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>11</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>48 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>48 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303880</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>2</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>None</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>None</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303887</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>12</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>50 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>50 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303881</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>6</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>42 CHEST L</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>42 CHEST L</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303879</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>1</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>None</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>None</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
            <Sizes>
                <Sku>21303877</Sku>
                <CompanyId>02</CompanyId>
                <Sequence>4</Sequence>
                <PlanUrl></PlanUrl>
                <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                <OnSale>false</OnSale>
                <StoreStockDisplay>Always</StoreStockDisplay>
                <LocalizedSizeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Description>38 CHEST</Description>
                    <SkuDisplayName>38 CHEST</SkuDisplayName>
                </LocalizedSizeList>
            </Sizes>
        </Colours>
        <ServiceProviderUrl></ServiceProviderUrl>
        <RewardCode>66</RewardCode>
        <IsDiscountable>true</IsDiscountable>
        <BrandImageURL>/25/BrandImage/fabiani.jpg</BrandImageURL>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <TFGMerchandisingId>194217AAAF6</TFGMerchandisingId>
        <Id>194217AAAF6</Id>
        <TFGMerchandisingDescription>TH CHASM DUFFEL L GREY</TFGMerchandisingDescription>
        <TFGMerchandisingDescriptionLong>TH CHASM DUFFEL L GREY</TFGMerchandisingDescriptionLong>
        <Type>ColourNoSize</Type>
        <SubType></SubType>
        <VideoUrl></VideoUrl>
        <TFGMerchandisingStatus>2</TFGMerchandisingStatus>
        <TFGMerchandisingStatusDescription>On Clearance</TFGMerchandisingStatusDescription>
        <TFGMerchandisingCreateDate>2017-03-28T07:36:58.567</TFGMerchandisingCreateDate>
        <TFGMerchandisingPisDate>2015-11-04T14:59:54.313</TFGMerchandisingPisDate>
        <TFGMerchandisingCommodity>4217</TFGMerchandisingCommodity>
        <TFGMerchandisingCommodityDescription>Duffel Bags</TFGMerchandisingCommodityDescription>
        <TFGMerchandisingBuyersClass>421702</TFGMerchandisingBuyersClass>
        <TFGMerchandisingBuyersClassDescription>Large</TFGMerchandisingBuyersClassDescription>
        <TFGMerchandisingMaterial>TPE Laminate</TFGMerchandisingMaterial>
        <TFGMerchandisingWeight>0.00</TFGMerchandisingWeight>
        <TFGMerchandisingCubeVolume>0</TFGMerchandisingCubeVolume>
        <TFGMerchandisingBrandName>Thule</TFGMerchandisingBrandName>
        <BrandCode>19</BrandCode>
        <CrossSellProductId1></CrossSellProductId1>
        <CrossSellProductId2></CrossSellProductId2>
        <CrossSellProductId3></CrossSellProductId3>
        <DisableCompareOption>false</DisableCompareOption>
        <DisableNextDayDelivery>false</DisableNextDayDelivery>
        <RequiresRica>false</RequiresRica>
        <RequiresId>false</RequiresId>
        <RequiresTVLicense>false</RequiresTVLicense>
        <RequiresDeposit>false</RequiresDeposit>
        <InstallmentAvailable>false</InstallmentAvailable>
        <StaffDiscountAllowed>true</StaffDiscountAllowed>
        <StaffDiscountOverride>false</StaffDiscountOverride>
        <MaxDiscountAllowed>40.00</MaxDiscountAllowed>
        <SizeChartIconUrl></SizeChartIconUrl>
        <PdfIconUrl></PdfIconUrl>
        <IsNavigable>true</IsNavigable>
        <TFGMerchandisingTypeCode></TFGMerchandisingTypeCode>
        <TFGMerchandisingTypeDescription></TFGMerchandisingTypeDescription>
        <Groups>
            <GroupSequence>1</GroupSequence>
            <GroupId>a9c1c190-5882-4e41-85a7-e0b14096f786</GroupId>
            <LocalizedGroupList>
                <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                <Group>Default</Group>
            </LocalizedGroupList>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>e07ef650-9719-4022-b0c0-c2837f04c856</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>End Use</Name>
                    <Value>Traveller</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>20b2e363-3364-4d54-90ce-51b26edebc2b</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Fabrication</Name>
                    <Value>TPE Laminate</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>35da6c1c-bd22-4858-a1d4-33508456d13c</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Capacity</Name>
                    <Value>90 l</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>b970e2f9-b7ff-407b-9b3b-2a82eab95e99</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Weight</Name>
                    <Value>1.2 kg</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>468d3dc8-16e8-4327-85c7-e118d25c82cd</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Dimensions</Name>
                    <Value>External height  33 cm
External length 74 cm
External depth  42 cm</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
            <Attributes>
                <AttributeId>996f1e59-97bc-4f99-8695-89c4e49c4f9c</AttributeId>
                <LocalizedAttributeList>
                    <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
                    <Name>Features</Name>
                    <Value>Oversized, wide mouth opening make it easy to pack and easy to get to your gear.
Side access makes it easy to reach the main compartment from any angle
Duffel straps stow cleanly along the side of the duffel.
Straps quickly convert the bag from a backpack to a duffel.
Durable, water proof tarpaulin fabric stands up on its own for easy packing but easily folds for storage.
Internal mesh pockets keep your gear organized.
External compression straps prevent bag contents from falling to the bottom of the bag when in backpack mode.
Padded bottom cushions your gear from the ground.
Locking zippers deter thieves (lock sold separately).
Exterior stash pocket stores small items.</Value>
                    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
                </LocalizedAttributeList>
            </Attributes>
        </Groups>
        <LocalizedProductList>
            <Locale>en_ZA</Locale>
            <DisplayName>Thule Chasm Duffel Large-Blue</DisplayName>
            <Description>Thule Chasm Duffel Large in Blue.With a wide mouth opening and removable backpack straps these rugged, weather resistant duffels are your go-to gear hauler for any adventure.</Description>
            <Widget1Url></Widget1Url>
            <Widget2Url></Widget2Url>
            <Widget3Url></Widget3Url>
            <Tabs>
                <Name>Product Information</Name>
                <Description></Description>
            </Tabs>
            <SizeChartUrl></SizeChartUrl>
            <SizeChartToolTip></SizeChartToolTip>
            <PdfUrl></PdfUrl>
            <PdfToolTip></PdfToolTip>
            <SeoTitle>Thule Chasm Duffel Large-Blue</SeoTitle>
        </LocalizedProductList>

        <ServiceProviderUrl></ServiceProviderUrl>
        <RewardCode>94</RewardCode>
        <IsDiscountable>true</IsDiscountable>
        <BrandImageURL>/19/BrandImage/thu.jpg</BrandImageURL>
        <Activity>Traveller</Activity>
    </Products>
</ProductFile>
```

But I get the following result.[image]

When I remove the for-each statement it works fine. Did read up on some people saying the for-each method is a bit messy, http://gregbee.ch/blog/using-xsl-for-each-is-almost-always-wrong 
Am I missing something?

Comment: your xml not parse. Please check

Comment: There's nothing with using `xsl:for-each` in XSLT, especially in your very simple case. Otherwise, they wouldn't have included it in the language specification! The main thing to bear in mind with `xsl:for-each` is that it is not actually a "loop" at all, but a mapping construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using `xsl:for-each`. The problem with your approach is that:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ProductFile/Products">
```

puts you in the context of `Products`. From here, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ProductFile/Products/Id"/>
```

selects nothing, because `ProductFile` is not a child of `Products`. You need to use the relative path to `Id`, which is simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
```

Likewise, you need to change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ProductFile/Products/LocalizedProductList/DisplayName"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="LocalizedProductList/DisplayName"/>
```

Comment: That does explain it really well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ProductFile/Products">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Id"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="LocalizedProductList/DisplayName"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
                    <xsl:for-each select="ProductFile/Products">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="Id"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="LocalizedProductList/DisplayName"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
```